# How to use the prop value inside a useEffect without adding it to the dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a scenario like this. Both message and level are coming from props. But I need to log the level only on message value change and when `message=== 'data'`, but not on `level` change. How can I achieve that? I implemented the useEffect hook like this. But it's giving me this eslint warning `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'level'. Either include it or remove the dependency array`. . So, what's the best way to get this fixed ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (message === 'data') {
        console.log('level : ', level);
    }
}, [message]);
```

Comment: can u add the code to a live editor?

Answer (score 3):

You can use useRef hook to prevent the warning

```
  const levelRef = useRef('');

  useEffect(() => {
    levelRef.current = level;
  }, [level]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message === 'data') {
      console.log(levelRef.current);
    }
  }, [message]);
```

or disable the eslint in this line

```
   useEffect(() => {
       if (message === 'data') {
           console.log(level);
       }
   }, [message]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Comment: just to add, approach with disable will work fine only until `console.log(level)` run in async way `....then(... console.log(level)`. Also disabling ESLint rule means you may miss to add _another_ dependency if code is changed, since no way to disable ESLint for particular variable in the list, but not to others. Though, first option is more verbose but much safer